# How do I relate separate models in Django 3

Tags: django-models

During the Covid-19 lockdown I have been working on transforming an old internal Flask application into a Django application (just for the fun and to try and get to know Django better).

Every hour our Active Directory and phonesystem delivere a CSV file with AD user details, and a list of keywords from the phone system.

I have written a small manger.py extension I can call via a cronjob. This extension clears the ADbruger model table and an repopulate the model through a Pandas DataFrame that I save via bulk_create.

The question that I have is how do I preserve content in related models? I import the base model data as described above with Pandas and bulk_create. Then I want to have an extra model, or inherited model, that gives the model the option to extend with users own keywords.

Is there a way to decouple the child model and reattach it later on, or is there a way for me to have two parallel models that are not inherited models, but kind of act like they are?

In my output (templates) I want to be able to show the users own keywords and not just the one I get in the original CSV output.

Here is the "main" model

```
class ADbruger(models.Model):
    initials = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=409)  # the data in the CSV is a csv list within a list

    def __str__(self):
        return initials
```

Here is the related, but not referenced model. The data saved here should persist even if the ADbruger model is cleared

```
class UsersOwnKeywords(models.Model):
    initials = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.initials
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around the problem by implementing a boolean field for active/not-active. The not active entries will be deleted after a time interval.